# Close app on back button in flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using flutter webview to open website. It has many navigation routes. When it navigates through any route and goes back I made it go back with: _webViewController.goBack();

If user is on homepage and presses back button I want app to be closed. I tried this:

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      if (_canGoBack) {
        _webViewController.goBack();
        return Future.value(false);
      }
      return Future.value(true); 
     }
```

bt it's not working

Comment: You want to close webview and get back to your app right?

Comment: how is the value of _canGoBack determiend? where do you set it's value in your code?

Comment: I want to close the app if I am on home page(which is a webview page). If I am not in homepage then on back button it must go back in history. Can i achieve this?

Comment: this is my goback code: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      if (_canGoBack) {
        _webViewController.goBack();
        return Future.value(false);
      }
      return Future.value(true); 
     }
@kforjan